# Cambiar valor de fecha actual

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, depuración

Estoy depurando con debug de NetBeans.

Necesito cambiar el valor de **fecha actual**, la cual pido con  `Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`.

> Cómo puedo cambiar el valor de esta fecha, mediante debug o de la
>   forma que sea, sin tener que cambiar la fecha del sistema de Windows
>   (y reiniciar NetBeans y WampServer..) como vengo haciendo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar el valor de la hora actual asignandole tu mismo la hora que deseas de este modo.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(5, 30, 45, 35); //05:30:45:35
System.out.println(time.getHour()); //5
System.out.println(time.getMinute()); //30
System.out.println(time.getSecond()); //45
System.out.println(time.getNano()); //35
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(); // tiempo actual
```

Si deseas cambiar la fecha puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1989, 11, 11); //1989-11-11
System.out.println(date.getYear()); //1989
System.out.println(date.getMonth()); //NOVEMBER
System.out.println(date.getDayOfMonth()); //11
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); //fecha actual
```

Comment: Hola, sé como crear o setear una fecha a estas alturas, el problema es que en mi programa hago por todos lados llamadas pidiendo la fecha actual, entonces sería engorroso modificar todo. Sé que con el debug de NetBeans se puede modificar valor de variables, pero esta no me la deja modificar con doble clik